# Shopping cart form footer

Tags: commerce

I wanto to display Prices with no decimal Places, in shopping cart footer (commerce order: order total ), but in the shopping cart view i found nothing to which does this. 
what shoud i do?

Comment: Do you want to remove the decimal places from that currency display sitewide, or just a certain place?

Answer (score 0):

Editing the view could be one solution but you can also do it via jquery i.e. capture the html inside the relevant div or span , then truncate the decimal part and then resupply the altered price value to the div or span. I think that should be very easy to do.

Answer (score 0):

It is because it set in line_item theme module ,go to `line_item` module directory(folder) in  `commerce` module (it is in commerce module submodules), then go to theme folder copy "commerce-line-item-summary.tpl.php" to your current theme, edit it.there is a where that the price will show.

this line exactly what you should change **(change $total) **

```
  <span class="line-item-total-label"><?php print $total_label; ?></span> <span class="line-  item-total-raw"><?php print $total; ?></span>
```

some thig like below work for you :

```
<span class="line-item-total-label"><?php print $total_label; ?></span> <span class="line-  item-total-raw"><?php print intval($total); ?></span>
```